# Create files using bash script with two or more arguments within another file

Tags: bash, for-loop, awk

I'm trying to create files using bash script with two arguments within another file.

Example:

My bash script file = `myscript.bash`
My source file with arguments = `masterfile.txt`

Here's what's inside the `masterfile.txt` file:

---

object1
record1

object2
record2

object4
record4

object3
record3

object5
record5

---

Now, when I run the myscript.bash file using `bash myscript.bash`, it should create folders & files with the contents of the files based on the `masterfile.txt` that it reads like the following:

## .../object1/object1.txt

Line1_Name: Dummy_Name1
Line2_Name: ***record1***
Line2_Name: Dummy_Name2

## .../object2/object2.txt

Line1_Name: Dummy_Name1
Line2_Name: ***record2***
Line3_Name: Dummy_Name2

## .../object4/object4.txt

Line1_Name: Dummy_Name1
Line2_Name: ***record4***
Line3_Name: Dummy_Name2

## .../object3/object3.txt

Line1_Name: Dummy_Name1
Line2_Name: ***record3***
Line3_Name: Dummy_Name2

## .../object5/object5.txt

Line1_Name: Dummy_Name1
Line2_Name: ***record5***
Line3_Name: Dummy_Name2

Can someone help, please? This requires expertise in bash scripting with multiple arguments, which I'm lacking. I tried the for each loop, which I'm stuck because there's two arguments. I was using the following sites as my reference when I formulated my script, which doesn't work :(.

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-loop-over-file/
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/awk-command-unixlinux-examples/

Comment: Welcome to SO, please wrap your samples and codes in CODE TAGS

Comment: See: [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to do, it really isn't that difficult and you have only 3 variables (1) the filename to read from `masterfile.txt`, (2) a variable to hold each line, and (3) a variable to hold the new outfile name from the line read before you read `"objectX"`.

The script itself is straight forward.

You set the filename based on the first argument to the script (or set to `masterfile.txt` by default). Empty the `ofile` variable (outfile name) and then loop reading lines.

If the line starts with `object`, create a directory and save the line as your `ofile` (base of the output filename). The if the line starts with `record`, print your 3-lines and zero `ofile` again, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

fname="${1:-masterfile.txt}"    ## filename [masterfile.txt (default)] 

[ -s "$fname" ] || {    ## validate file exists and is non-empty
    printf "error: %s empty or doesn't exist.\n" "$fname" >&2
    exit 1
}

ofile=      ## set outfile variable empty

## read each line in file, handle non-POSIX eof
while read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do
    if [[ $line =~ ^object ]]; then     ## if line starts with "object"
        mkdir -p "$line" || {           ## create/validate directory
            printf "error: failed to create %s.\n" "$line" >&2
            exit 1
        }
        ofile="$line"                   ## set outfile name to line
    ## otherwise, if line starts with "record" and outfile name not-empty
    elif [[ $line =~ ^record ]] && [ -n "$ofile" ]; then
        ## output your 3 lines
        printf "Line1_Name: Dummy_Name1\nLine2_Name: %s\nLine3_name: Dummy_Name2\n" \
            "$line" > "${ofile}/${ofile}.txt"
        ofile=  ## set outfile empty again
    fi
done < "$fname"
```

**Directory Content Before Running Script**

Before running the script, the directory contains:

```
$ tree
.
├── masterfile.txt
└── myscript.sh

0 directories, 2 files
```

**Example Script Use**

Run the script:

```
$ bash myscript.sh masterfile.txt
```

**Directory Content After Running Script**

Afterwards, the directory contains:

```
$ tree
.
├── masterfile.txt
├── myscript.sh
├── object1
│   └── object1.txt
├── object2
│   └── object2.txt
├── object3
│   └── object3.txt
├── object4
│   └── object4.txt
└── object5
    └── object5.txt
```

**Output File Content**

Checking `object1.txt` and `object5.txt`, you will have:

```
$ cat object1/object1.txt
Line1_Name: Dummy_Name1
Line2_Name: record1
Line3_name: Dummy_Name2

$ cat object5/object5.txt
Line1_Name: Dummy_Name1
Line2_Name: record5
Line3_name: Dummy_Name2
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions. There is more than one way to approach this. `awk` would be a good alternative.

**Using `awk`**

Doing essentially the same thing using `awk` will be a bit more efficient. Below accomplishes the same thing is `myscript.sh` above. The only change is that creating the directory has been delayed until the until the `recordX` line is encountered. The `system()` command in used to create the directory with the string stored in `scmd`, which is `"mkdir -p "` concatenated with the `objectX` line, e.g.

```
awk -v ofile="" '
    /^object/{ ofile=$0 }
    /^record/ && length(ofile) {
        scmd = "mkdir -p " ofile
        system(scmd)
        printf "Line1_Name: Dummy_Name1\nLine2_Name: %s\nLine3_name: Dummy_Name2\n", $0 > ofile"/"ofile".txt"
        ofile=""
    }
' masterfile.txt
```

---

**Edit Based on Question Clarification**

If `objectX` and `recordX` can be anything, and you are using the line pairs, separated by an empty-line, to set the name and contents of the directory/filename and `Line2...`, there are very few changes needed. In the script above, the tests for `object` and `record` provided additional validations of the content, but are not entirely necessary to the script.

To eliminate the checks on `objectX` and `recordX` and rely only on the newline, you need only add an additional check at the top to check if the line read was empty, e.g.

```
## read each line in file, handle non-POSIX eof
while read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do
    [ -z "$line" ] && continue;         ## empty line, skip, get next
    ...
```

Now you can remove the reliance on any of the content of `masterfile.txt` and simply use the file structure. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

fname="${1:-masterfile.txt}"    ## filename [masterfile.txt (default)] 

[ -s "$fname" ] || {    ## validate file exists and is non-empty
    printf "error: %s empty or doesn't exist.\n" "$fname" >&2
    exit 1
}

ofile=      ## set outfile variable empty

## read each line in file, handle non-POSIX eof
while read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do
    [ -z "$line" ] && continue;         ## empty line, skip, get next
    if [[ -z "$ofile" ]]; then          ## output file not set
        mkdir -p "$line" || {           ## create/validate directory
            printf "error: failed to create %s.\n" "$line" >&2
            exit 1
        }
        ofile="$line"                   ## set outfile name to line
    ## otherwise, if outfile name not-empty
    elif [ -n "$ofile" ]; then
        ## output your 3 lines
        printf "Line1_Name: Dummy_Name1\nLine2_Name: %s\nLine3_name: Dummy_Name2\n" \
            "$line" > "${ofile}/${ofile}.txt"
        ofile=  ## set outfile empty again
    fi
done < "$fname"
```

(the file/directory creation is the same)

**Updated `awk` Solution**

Similarly, the `awk` solution can be updated to work based off the line-pairs as well. Here the `ofile` variable is used to hold the output filename and used as a flag to determine whether to create the directory and write the current line out. The built-in `NF` (number of fields) variable is used to check/skip the blank line:

```
awk -v ofile="" '
    NF && ofile=="" { ofile=$0; next }
    NF && ofile!="" {
        scmd = "mkdir -p " ofile
        system(scmd)
        printf "Line1_Name: Dummy_Name1\nLine2_Name: %s\nLine3_name: Dummy_Name2\n", $0 > ofile"/"ofile".txt"
        ofile=""
    }
' masterfile.txt
```

(output is the same -- you can just copy and middle-mouse paste on the command line in the same directory with `masterfile.txt` to test)

Give the updates a try and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: The problem here is that `object*` & `record*` variables could be different names, which I forgot to mention. So the correct script should be a little different from what you've just posted.

Comment: The trick there is that the contents of masterfile.txt are pair of two lines/rows (each line/row representing a variable value) separated by an empty line/row. We have to treat the first line/row of the pairs as the one we use to create a folder and a file and the 2nd line/row of the two lines/rows should be part of what's in the content of the file that gets created.

Comment: Oh, that will make a difference. Let me take another look and I'll see if I can drop an edit for you.

Comment: @khal-el - see the updated script and `awk` solutions posted as additions below the original answer.

Comment: I didn't try the updated `awk` solution but your updated bash script worked like a charm! Awesome! You're the man, David!

Comment: Good, glad it helped. There is always more than one way to *skin-the-cat*.